# How to interpret standard deviation in monthly units purchased

Tags: standard-deviation

So I have a set of data, units purchased per month over a 4 year period. I have about 3000 different items, but here are 2 items as an example:

Item 1: Mean 24 STDEVA 18 It has purchases practically every single month of each year.
Item 2: Mean 12 STDEVA 15 It has at least 1 or 3 months with purchases of 0.

What I'm trying to determine is which items are safer to purchase (inventory) such that I wont be so affected by large stdev?

Iow, 18 of 24 is still a pretty big number. Its telling me that 68% of all values in that set are +/-18 units away from 24. That could be as low as 6 or as high as 42. On the other hand, 15 of 12 is just as bad (-3 or 27).  But looking at the values I would definitely choose buying items in the first set with more confidence.

How should I use the std dev to determine my safety level of purchases for a given year?

Set 1: 14,80,14,52,12,71,23,12,32,9,14,28,2,9,13,74,25,62,18,58,19,21,14,11,6,25,37,1,46,48,83,29,8,26,50,15,26,66,19,65,93,4,16,98,62,24,0,0,6,5,33,0,1,70,0

Set 2: 4,4,13,30,22,50,16,4,60,16,31,35,10,10,10,8,10,23,0,3,18,0,10,8,37,73,2,11,9,18,4,0,3,11,19,3,7,0,3,0,0,2,0,4,4,14,11,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0

I understand they're not normally distributed but most of my items don't have a normal distribution?

Comment: You seem to be handicapping yourself at the outset.  Why not examine the actual distributions of the data rather than attempting to summarize them with means and standard deviations?

Comment: How do you know that 68% of all values are +/- units away from 24.I think you are a using a large, normal approximately result here that I'm not sure would hold.

Comment: OK is there a different way to analyze the data?  I mean is there a numerical way to establish which sets are more reliable around their means than others?

Comment: I don't understand your example data.  You say you have 4 years' worth of data, but you don't have 12 x 4 = 48 data points; you have 55 data points.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I actually have from June 2015 to Dec 2019